# Jinja template - hide empty table

Tags: jinja2

I have a remarks table in my template that does not always has an value.
Is it possible to hide this table if it's empty?

Hiding the table header is no problem using the following code;

```
{%if report_comment%}Remarks{%endif%}
```

Comment: What is the rest of the code on that page? Without it, that would be hard to answer you.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have access to the word based template. The source data/code comes from third party software which I cannot access.